# Change the language using BASH command

Tags: bash

How can I change the language in the BASH, s.t. the error messages will be shown in English?
This would allow me to post the error messages directly, without translating them.
Using `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`and `vi ~/.bashrc` didn't work.

Comment: What is the `locale` output before and after setting the locale. And this is a question better suited for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: try `en_EN.UTF-8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `LANG` environment variable:

```
export LANG=C
```

`en_GB.UTF-8` works, too. But put it in `~/.profile`. And restart your login shell.

Or put a file in `/etc/profile.d` for a system wide configuration.